# Select tag not able to collect all values in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML form where select tag is used for the inputs, with 4 options where in the last one is named as other.When selected other a text field comes and the input can be given:

HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()=='Other:'){
    $('#other').show().focus();
    }else{
    $('#other').val('').hide();
    }
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>Options : </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="Options">
    <option value="Option-1">Option-1</option>
    <option value="Option-2">Option-2</option>
    <option value="Option-3">Option-3</option>
    <option value="Other:">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="other" style="display:none" name="other"  style="display:none"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

While inserting in the DB am only able to insert the value added in the text field. Where in the option 1,2,3 are not getting collected and inserted in DB.

PHP code to insert the value in mysql DB:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Options = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Options'], $_POST['other']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (Options) VALUES ('$Options');
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

i want to collect the option which ever is selected and inserted in DB. Currently am only able to insert the other option where the data will be entered through text field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for array of options list ??if so codepen url -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QEEqbx

Comment: try to Use separate escape srting $Options = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Options);
$other = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $other);

Comment: @Gopal..if i use two seperate escape strings how will the insert statement be..?

Comment: @Naga Sai...am looking to collect the options which ever selected. But in the escape string its not getting collected except the other option (text field).

Comment: For selected option , use document.getElementById('optionsList').value....if you add attribute id and its value as "optionsList"- to the select tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if else to switch between the values depending on that input has been given via the selectlist.

```
if($_POST["Options"] !== "Other:"){
    $Options = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Options']);
}else{
    $Options = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['other']);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (Options) VALUES ('$Options')";
// ...
```